# Hide Header and Footer for specific Components in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on react js project. I need to hide the header and footer for some specific components. I tried it with the following code snippet in the header component.

```
class Navbar extends Component {
state = {}
render() {
    const {user} = this.props;
    if (window.location.pathname === "/sign-in" || window.location.pathname === "/sign-up" || window.location.pathname === "/vehicles/reservation") return null;
    return (
        <header className="bg-gray-200 sticky z-50 h-20 md:h-auto top-0">...</header>);
    }
}
```

Since the render method is called only when there is a change, the above condition is not checked every time.
How do I make a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a state variable as a props from parent component, for updating child component.

Parent componente:

```
state = {
    updateNavbar: false,
  }

//when is necessary update navbar:
this.setState(state => ({
      updateNavbar: !updateNavbar,
    }))

...
<Navbar updateNavbar={this.state.updateNavbar}>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want React to interact with the URL, you usually use a router. [react-router](https://reactrouter.com/) is the popular one.

Comment: Thank u for your support. I have used react-router to route components. But with the above solution, the navbar doesn't hide until the page reloads.

Comment: You need to get your `location` from the router instead of the window: `const location = useLocation()`